# Approximating the modulus of a Complex Function near a point.

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics

Let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb{C}$, and let $z_0 \in \Omega$.
Let $f$ be analytic on $\Omega$.

Let $z=z_0+re^{i\theta}$ for $r$ small.

Assume that $f(z_0) \neq 0$ and $f'(z_0) \neq 0$.

I want to show $|f(z)| = |f(z_0)|\big(1+\lambda r \cos(\theta+\phi)+O(r^2)\big)$
where $\displaystyle \frac{f'(z_0)}{f(z_0)}=\lambda e^{i\phi}, \lambda > 0.$

Now:

$f(z)=f(z_0)+f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+O((z-z_0)^2) = $
$  f(z_0)+f'(z_0)(re^{i\theta})+O(r^2) =$

$|f(z_0)|\big | 1+\lambda r e^{i(\theta+\phi)} + O(r^2) \big | =$
$|f(z_0)|\big | 1+\lambda r (\cos(\theta+\phi)+i\sin(\theta + \phi)) + O(r^2) \big |$

It is not clear to me how I finish this off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us for simplicity write $\psi = \theta + \phi$. When dealing with absolute moduli, it is often convenient to square them. Here, that yields

$$\begin{align}
\lvert 1 + \lambda re^{i\psi}\rvert^2 &= \lvert (1+\lambda r\cos\psi) + i\lambda r\sin\psi\rvert^2\\
&= (1+\lambda r\cos\psi)^2 + \lambda^2 r^2\sin^2\psi\\
&= 1 + 2\lambda r\cos\psi + \lambda^2r^2.
\end{align}$$

Taking the square root, using $\sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \frac{x}{2} + O(x^2)$ yields

$$\lvert 1 +\lambda re^{i\psi}\rvert = 1 + \lambda r\cos\psi + \frac12\lambda^2r^2 + O(\lambda^2r^2) = 1 + \lambda r\cos\psi + O(r^2)$$

as desired.

Comment: Am I right that it was important to do an approximation of sqrt(1+x) w/ x near 0 because the thing that will replace x is also near 0?

Comment: Yes, since we're looking at small $r$, we need to approximate the square root near $1$, and that is best done by considering $\sqrt{1+x}$ near $0$.